# Using htaccess to redirect to mobile version unless user wants to "force desktop version"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, web

I have the following .htaccess file to redirect to the mobile version of my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/mobile [L,R=302]
```

However, I need to add a condition for mobile users to be able to request the desktop site.

I've searched around a bit and haven't found a simple answer. I just need to have an url such as http://www.example.com/?desktop to avoid the redirection to /mobile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/mobile [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly, I didn't know you could simply add conditions like that.