# Redirecting non mobile visitors to domain.com/home

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have an magento shop running (www.domain) for what i also created an speed door (Accesible through: www.domain.com/home). Now i also installed a mobile theme. the mobile theme is not on a subdomain, but due the design option in Magento, Magento recognizes mobile users en direct them to the mobile site (also just www.domain.com).

Now what i want to do is when desktop users visit www.domain.com that the are redirected to www.domain.com/home and when mobile users visit they will go to www.domain.com

I tried adding the following to .htaccess file in the Magento root, but no success.

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\
>   NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC] RewriteRule ^$ home/
>   [L,R]

Is there any other possibily, doesn't have to be through .htaccess.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `but no success` is what? You get a not found page? It doesn't redirect? It takes you to the mobile?

Comment: It redirects everything to home (also Mobile traffic)

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS to redirect.  Here is an example to redirect different operating systems:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; 
var isWin8 = ua.indexOf("windows nt 6.2") > -1;
var isBB = ua.indexOf("bb10") > -1;

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) {
    document.location = "http://url for ipad";
}

else if(isAndroid) {
 window.location = 'https://url for android';
}
      else if(isWin8) {
 window.location = 'http://url for win8';
}

else if(isBB)  {
     window.location = "http://url for bb";
  }

else
 {
window.location = "http://url "
 }

  </script>
```

Comment: Hi Jon Thanks for you answer.

where do i put the JS?

Comment: did you try it out?  I have a page that has no content, just redirects, so the JS is the whole page, no head etc.  Id stick it in the head of a normal html page.  But try with error till you get the result you want.

Comment: Hi Jon i tried it..

but JS and HTML redirects Load the page first and then, the redirect. so it thanks a lot of time, so i guess i need to do it through htaccess

Comment: the js is performed where it is on the page.  So the HTML wont be read till after the JS is executed. So if the JS redirects the HTML will never be read.  Im not sure why you think the html is loading or where the code is, or the redirect works when you see the html load.  etc.  re htacess are you sure you are on apache?

Comment: when i tried to redirect from domain.com to domain/home through html. Domain.com loads for an little bit and the direct to the (domain.com/home) which terminates the use of the speeddoor.


Yes i am on apache from siteground. I tried the follow just to try the concept;


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/ [L,R=302]


What happens here is the mobile is redirected to /home and desktop to domain.com. But i need this the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I added the follow to my .htaccess file. What happens now is that mobile is redirect to Domain.com/home and desktop traffic is directed to domain.com.

So something about this function is working, but I need this the other way around..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: did you see these posts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698454/mobile-site-redirect-to-desktop-version-using-htaccess    &   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241437/using-htaccess-to-redirect-to-mobile-version-unless-user-wants-to-force-desktop

Comment: Did saw the first one. That did the trick, only i did add the wordpress rules, since i use magento.

Thanks you very much